# Two nested DLLs

Tags: c#, deployment, encapsulation, dll

We have a dll file; let's say X.DLL.

We are now writing another DLL, let's say "A.DLL" that uses some (very few) of the functions of X.DLL. We have no access to source code of X.DLL. Also, we don't want to give our clients X.DLL along with A.DLL.

Instead, we want to encapsulate X.DLL within A.DLL, so that distributing A.DLL will suffice.

Is it something possible?

Your help is appreciated.

Novice Coder

Comment: Out of interest, why don't you want to give them X.DLL?

Comment: The reason is that we don't want them to have all the functionality included in X.DLL. X.DLL and A.DLL will be used to develop some application and we want them to have functions which are included in A.DLL only.

Comment: Yea, why don't you want to give them the .DLL? trying to avoid license fees?

Comment: It seems X.DLL isn't something you wrote or you'd have the source.

Comment: X.DLL is not something we wrote or we have access the source. But we have full license to distribute it with our applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en)

> ILMerge is a utility for merging
>   multiple .NET assemblies into a single
>   .NET assembly. It works on executables
>   and DLLs alike and comes with several
>   options for controlling the processing
>   and format of the output. See the
>   accompanying documentation for
>   details.

Comment: I have a scenario where X.dll is not compatible with .Net environment or latter versions of Windows OS. Also we don't have the source code of X.dll. It only runs/registeres in VB6.0 environment. In that case we want to embed this X.dll and create a new .dll in vb6.0 that is compatible with .Net. Do you know a utility for such a task?

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question with c#.

If these are managed assembly DLL's, which they will be if the code is c#, then you can do exactly what you want with [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

copy source code from x.dll to a.dll with required functions.
or split x.dll to two dll's

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we have no access to source code of x.dll.

Comment: They don't have the source for X.DLL

Comment: ops sorry )
if it is written in any .net language you can stiil disassamble it )

Comment: you can use reflector for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to encapsulate one dll into another.
A way out may be if you can obtain a lib from the X.DLL vendors, and statically link to it with your code.
A hack out may be carrying the X.DLL as a resource inside you dll, then unpack and load in in the runtime.

Comment: Sorry ULysses, but it certainly isn't "impossible". Ill advised, but not impossible.

Comment: it's not impossible it does however requires emitting the byte code your eslf or similar

Comment: Depends on the nature of the DLL's. If they're managed code, ILMerge could do the trick. If unmanaged, you'd have to hack around big time with Win32 LoadLibrary.

Comment: sure, i didn't pay attention to the c# tag. I was thinking of a windows native dll